# automatically create new post for each custom taxonomy term inserted by user

Tags: php, wordpress

Alright, here's what I'm trying to achieve. I have a custom post type called 'Campaigns' and a custom taxonomy called 'Countries' that has been assigned to the campaign post type. When a user adds a new country (tags a new country to a campaign) I want to duplicate the current post, name the new post the name of the country just assigned, and make it a child of the current post.

Currently, I'm hooking into 'set_object_terms' and on the save of the terms determining what new terms have been created. I'm then trying to insert a new post for each of the terms, however I'm creating an infinite loop. I've tried creating a global to stop the loop, but I'm running into some issues. This is what I have so far.

```
$GLOBALS['control_campaign_count'] = 0;

add_action('set_object_terms','save_terms',10,6);
function save_terms($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids) {

//Assuming we only want terms from specific taxonomy
//If not simply remove this conditional
$our_taxonomy = 'country';
if($taxonomy == $our_taxonomy){

    //Added terms are specified terms, that did not already exist
    $added_tt_ids = array_diff($tt_ids, $old_tt_ids);

    if ($append) {
        //If appending terms - nothing was removed
        $removed_tt_ids = array();
    } else {
        //Removed terms will be old terms, that were not specified in $tt_ids
        $removed_tt_ids = array_diff($old_tt_ids, $tt_ids);
    }

    /*, 
      Currently we have the taxonomy term IDs */


    foreach($added_tt_ids as $term){
        $added_terms[] = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id',$term,$taxonomy);

        $name = $added_terms->name;
        echo $name;

        // Add New Post 
        add_action('wp_insert_post', 'add_new_campaign');
        function add_new_campaign() {

            if($GLOBALS['control_campaign_count'] === 1) {
                return;
            }

            $GLOBALS['control_campaign_count']++;

            $new_post_arguments = array(
                'post_title' => 'Japan',
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type'   => 'campaigns',
                'post_parent' => 1156
            );

            $id = wp_insert_post($new_post_arguments);
            update_post_meta($id, 'keywords');
        }
    }


    foreach($removed_tt_ids as $term){
        $removed_terms[] = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id',$term,$taxonomy);


    }

    //$added_terms contains added term objects
    //$removed_terms contains removed term objects
}
}
```

Ideas? Thoughts on a better way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the same hook. But..

Here's the code I used, which worked well for me:

```
add_action( 'set_object_terms', 'auto_create_campaigns', 10, 6 );
function auto_create_campaigns( $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids ) {
    if ( 'campaigns' !== get_post_type( $object_id ) || 'country' !== $taxonomy ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $append ) {
        $term_ids = $tt_ids;
    } else {
        $term_ids = array_diff( $tt_ids, $old_tt_ids );
    }

    $post = get_post( $object_id, ARRAY_A );
    unset( $post['ID'] );

    foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
        // Remove the hook (to avoid infinite loop).
        remove_action( 'set_object_terms', 'auto_create_campaigns', 10, 6 );

        $term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );
        if ( is_wp_error( $term ) || empty( $term ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $post['post_title'] = $term->name;
        $post['post_name'] = $term->slug;
        $post['post_parent'] = $object_id;

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

        /*if ( $post_id ) {
            // Copy the parent's "countries".
            // wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy );
        }*/

        /*if ( $post_id ) {
            // Copy the parent's custom fields.
            // ..
        }*/

        // Add it back.
        add_action( 'set_object_terms', 'auto_create_campaigns', 10, 6 );
    }
}
```

That code only copies the standard post data such as `post_title`; however, it is possible to also copy the parent post's "countries"/terms and/or custom fields.

### UPDATE

It's probably better to *remove the hook and add it back* (at the *end* of each iteration in the `foreach` loop) than using the global `$_in_auto_create_campaigns`.

Hopefully that also helps you with the grandchild posts:

> How can I set the terms, allow grandchild posts, and not get in an
>   infinite loop?

(You can also try [this](https://pastebin.com/P640Mi8d), which uses the same method, but the *`remove_action()` and `add_action()`* are placed *near the `wp_set_post_terms()`*)

Comment: This is great, works for me as well. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I've tried setting the term tags for the created post and it works, however, I'm only able to go one level deep as the conditional check $_in_auto_create_campaigns gets triggered. I'm looking to have a master post such as Marketing > Child post of country (which is a terms in Marketing) > Grandchild post of business (which is a term the user can set in the country). How can I set the terms, allow grandchild posts, and not get in an infinite loop?